# Vue input field with v-model doesn't update on the mount

Tags: vue.js

I am working on this Vue app where I have a modal with 3 steps. In the second and third steps, there are input fields updating with v-model and they work on user input with no problem.

However, if you go back to the second step from the third one, input fields seem to be empty. They update only if there is another input event triggered(not supposed to be in those fields).

A very crude example of the flow:

main-modal-page:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <first-step v-if="activeStep==='first'"/>
   <second-step v-if="activeStep==='second'"/>
   <third-step v-if="activeStep==='third'"/>
  <button @click="nextStep">Next</button>
  <button @click="previousStep">Previous</button>
 
 </div>
</template>
```

First step

```
<template>
 <div>
   <input v-model="model.type type="select"/>
 </div>
</template>
```

Second step

```
<template>
 <div>
   <input v-model="model.header"/>
   <div>
     <input v-model="model.article.content"/>
     <my-radio-button @input="$emit('input',value)"
                      type="radio">
   </div>
   <other-content/>
 </div>
</template>
```

Here an input event triggered by the radio button updates input fields and they show the content of the model.

Third step

```
<template>
 <div>
   <input v-model="model.header"/>
   <some-other-content/>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: "They update only if there is another input event triggered(not supposed to be in those fields)." Can you clarify here?

Comment: In the second step, there is an input field with v-model. If you come back from the third step this field is empty even if the model has data. Bur if you click on the radio button input field updates immediately and displays the data. The same field is used in the third step too but behaves as expected.